# Rails/PostgreSQL problem: PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to run my tests for my app but I keep getting both this errors:

> PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
>
> PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already

I'be read all previous answers and it seems to be, for everybody else, either a missing password or a misconfiguration of the pg_hba.conf file.

This is how my database.yml looks like:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: true
  host: localhost
  username: postgres
  password: <password>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: <dev-db>
  host: <dev-host>
  username: <dev-user>
  password: <dev-pass>

test:
  <<: *default
  database: <test-db>
```

I already checked the pg_hba.conf config file and its configured to md5 for all entries listed.

Any clues to what might be the problem?

I'm running PostgreSQL 10, Rails 5.2.3 on Ruby 2.5.5, on a Macbook with Mojave.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Does your postgres user actually have a password set on it? Typically there is no password for the default postgres user, so this is something you would need to have gone out of your way to do; judging by the error message, it sounds like you are using the default posgres user and have not gone out of your way to set a password in the PostgreSQL CLI.

I suggest stripping it down to a very basic default, functional config like:

```
postgres: &postgres
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
development:
  <<: *postgres
  database: project_name_development
test:
  <<: *postgres
  database: project_name_test
```

Then incrementally add back additional configuration options one at a time, confirming that each one works before adding the next. Env vars also may not be available to database.yml depending on your project configuration and installed gems.

Comment: Yes, it does. I did try stripping configs as you suggest and it justs repeat the pattern, first it says I'm giving it the wrong password and then, with it set, it says the error again.

Comment: So it says you have the wrong password if you *totally remove* the username and password lines from your database.yml?

Comment: Yes. But the problem is not with the DB connection, I can perfectly access the DB from any other source, including the app code. if I set the test to point to devel, for example, I get the same errors, even though I know the connection works just fine.